# Coin tosses until doubling amount

Tags: probability

Two friends are playing the following game:
The first player named A has an initial amount of M dollars. By tossing a fair coin once, he bets 1 dollar and if he gets heads, player B gives him 1 dollar, while if he gets tails, A gives his 1 dollar to B. The game ends when A doubles his money or when he loses it all. What is the probability he doubles his money?

OK at the first coin toss he starts with M dollars and bets 1. With probability 1/2 he now has M+1 and with probability 1/2 he has M-1. At the second round, he bets another dollar and with probability 1/2 he has M+2 and with probability 1/2 he has M-2 and so on. Since the events are independent, the total probability of winning each time is 1/2*1/2 etc.

How do we calculate the total probability?
I clarify that each time he bets only 1 dollar.

Comment: what size M are we talking about ? if M=1  then 1 toss is sufficient to double the money 50% of the time. if M=10 then it's more complicated, if M=100 even more so, etc.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee: Thanks for your comment. I am looking for the formula, not the exact number. Actually we are looking for the probability to have exactly M more wins than loses.

Comment: The number of tosses can be infinitely large. If a is the number of wins and b the number of loses, it must be a-b=M. Probability for each (a)=Probability(b)=1/2.

Answer (score 5):

If we can supose that he has a finite amount of dollars, then both cases have probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

You can think this as the [random walk problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk).

Edit: It's clear that both cases have equal probability, by the argument that stated Zubin Mukerjee on the comments. We only need to use that the probability to be playing the game forever is zero, in order to be able to claim that the probability is  exactly $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain a little further, as I am not familiar with the random walk? My guess is that the problem is equivalent with finding the probability of having M more wins than loses in a fair coin flipping game.

Comment: Yes. By symmetry, the case in which he doubles his money is exactly as likely as the case in which he loses it all.

Comment: For comparison: Starting with $M$ dollars and using boundaries of $2M$ and $0$ (as in your question) is the same as starting with $0$ dollars and using boundaries of $+M$ and $-M$ dollars. The second example really highlights the symmetry of the problem. The probability of reaching $M$ before $-M$, by symmetry, must be exactly equal to the probability of reaching $-M$ before $M$.

Answer (score 2):

This game has a specific name. That called *Gambler's ruin*.

Let $P(x)$ be the probability that A wins the game with $x$ dollars. It's clear that $P(2M) = 1$, $P(0) = 0$ and $P(x) = \frac{1}{2}P(x-1) + \frac{1}{2}P(x+1)$.

By some algebraic work on $P(x) = \frac{1}{2}P(x-1) + \frac{1}{2}P(x+1)$, we have $P(x+1) = 2P(x) - P(x-1)$.

- $P(2) = 2P(1) - P(0) = 2P(1) - 0 = 2P(1)$
- $P(3) = 2P(2) - P(1) = 2\times2P(1) - P(1) = 3P(1)$
- $P(4) = 2P(3) - P(2) = 2\times3P(1) - P(2) = 4P(1)$
- ...

$\Rightarrow P(x) = xP(1)$ and we know that $P(2M) = 1 \Rightarrow P(2M) = 2M\times P(1) = 1 \Rightarrow P(1) = \frac{1}{2M}$

Thus, the probability of winning A with $M$ initial dollars is $P(M) = M\times P(1) = M \times \frac{1}{2M} = \frac{1}{2}$

---

Here, I explain more about $P(x)$. By a simple use of Total Probability Theorem, we have

$P(x) = P(x|\text{A wins in the last round})\times P(\text{A wins in the last round}) + P(x|\text{A looses in the last round})\times P(\text{A looses in the last round}) = \frac{1}{2}P(x|\text{A wins in the last round}) + \frac{1}{2} P(x|\text{A looses in the last round}) = \frac{1}{2}P(x+1) + \frac{1}{2}P(x-1)$

Comment: The only case in which you win the game is having $2M$ dollars. Your formula for $P(x)$ doesn't make sense to me. EDIT: Also, the final result is incorrect. The probability of winning must be the same as the probability of losing, by symmetry. Both are $1/2$.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: I fix the problem

Comment: @Hasan Heydari: But in the problem you describe, the gambler does not reduce his state when he loses. In my case he does.

Comment: @HasanHeydari It sounds like $P(x)$ is the probability that you *eventually* win the game, given that you currently have $x$ dollars. With this interpretation your answer makes a lot more sense. :)

Comment: So for example if we have a string like WLWWWLLWL...WLWLW, it must be (total W) - (total L)=M.

Comment: @Alex.vollenga I think this answer is solving the same question. However, I think it is much easier to use a symmetry argument.

Comment: @Alex.vollenga: Suppose A has $x$ dollars. With probability $0.5$ he win 1 dollar and his total dollars reaches to $x+1$ and with probability of $0.5$ he looses 1 dollar and his total dollars reaches to $x-1$. Thus, $P(x) = 0.5P(x+1)+ 0.5P(x-1)$. Got it?

Comment: @Hasan Heydari: I agree with your formula to compute the probability of winning in the (x+1) game. But in our case, aren't we looking for the TOTAL probability to win with a total difference of M? In my example with the 3 dollars, we win the first dollar with Probability 1/2, then again the second dollar with another 1/2 (so far 1/4??) then again the third dollar with total 1/8, provided of course we do not loose in the meantime!

Comment: This is *not* the gambler's ruin problem.  That refers specifically to a gambler with finite money wither increasing bets to cover losses; or to the related situation where the gambler gambles on (even a game in his favour) against an opponent with infinite money and no win condition.

In both cases, the gambler has P(1) of losing all their money - which should make it clear that this is not the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, the probability of doubling your money is $\frac{1}{2}$ due to symmetry arguments.  The probabilities of winning or losing $1 in one bet are equal; the patterns of individual wins and loses that leads to doubling your money are mirror images of equally likely patterns that lead to you losing it all. Another way to see that is that the game is symmetric and fair between the two players.  If they both start with M then when one has doubled his money, the other has lost it all.

You can perform detailed calculations if you wish but they will be fairly messy.

Fewer than $M$ bets and obviously the game cannot be complete.

Exactly $M$ bets and it could be complete.  Fairly obviously, the probability of having doubled your money is $\frac{1}{2}^M$ and losing all is the same.  Unless $M = 1$, these will not add up to $1$ as they will be a probability that the game is not complete.

A game of length $M + 1$ is not possible.  $M + 1$ wins will overshoot your target and you should have stopped.  $1$ loss will mean that you have only reached $M - 1$ and you should not stop yet.

A game of length $M + 2$ is possible: $M + 1$ wins and $1$ loss which was any time except the last two.  The probability of this with a particular point for the loss is $\frac{1}{2}^{M+2}$ but there are $M$ occasions on which the loss could occur so a game of length $M + 2$ has probability $M \times \frac{1}{2}^{M+2}$.

To get a full answer, you could work a few more cases, guess a pattern to the answers and then prove that by induction.

Expanded explanation of my symmetry idea.

Suppose that you start with $\$3$ so the game will end when you reach $\$6$ or $\$0$.  These patterns of individual wins and loses (any many more) will bring you to $\$6$.

Length 3: WWW.  Probability $\frac{1}{2}^3$.

Length 4: None

Length 5: LWWWW, WLWWW, WWLWW.  All probability $\frac{1}{2}^5$.

Length 6: None

Length 7: LLWWWWW, LWLWWWW, WLWLWWW, and many more. All probability $\frac{1}{2}^7$.

Etc.

Now swap all of the Ws and Ls.  You will get another set of patterns with the same probabilities but these will lead to $\$0$.

For every pattern of wins and loses that leads to doubling your money, there is an equally likely pattern that leads to losing it all (and vice versa).

As some have commented, if you score it slightly differently and track how much up or down you are then the game ends at $+M$ or $-M$ and the symmetry should be more obvious.

Also considering playing debt notes rather than dollar bills so that the effect of passing the "winnings" is reversed.  The probability of winning with *anti-money* will be the same as losing with regular money.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think it is symmetric at all. It would be fully symmetric if we required only 1 dollar difference after N tosses (so one would have N/2 (rounded up) +1 wins. I clarify that each time we bet only 1 dollar, not our total amount. If we start, for example, with 3 dollars, we first bet 1. Then we can end up with either 4 or 2. We continue betting one more dollar. We end up with 5 or 1 and so on. Once we reach 6, we stop. This probability is not 1/2, for sure. It is a lot less.

Comment: I'll expand my answer and see if that makes my idea clearer.

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated!

Comment: Let's put it this way: Starting with 3 dollars, what is the probability we finish with 6 dollars (before going bankrupt) by betting one dollar at a time?

Comment: Has my expanded explanation helped?

Comment: Yes, very much. Many thanks to all of you. I managed to understand why the total probability to either win or lose is 1/2

Comment: It is useful, but sometimes difficult, to spot these symmetries.  Once I was analysing the game solitaire which you have a board with marbles in holes.  It starts with one empty hole (usually the centre), a move is to jump one  marble over another  and into a hole.  The one that is jumped over is removed.  The objective is to reverse the situation so that one marble is left in the starting position.  In some games, it is easier to analyse from the end backwards.  So, I tried this but I soon realised that it was the same game but holes were jumping over holes and creating marbles.